# where to enter command line for mysqladmin

Tags: mysql

So I'm configuring my database.

I've found these two guides which have a lot of the commands of what I need to use.

http://www.tecmint.com/mysql-backup-and-restore-commands-for-database-administration/

basically any of these commands

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/programs-client.html

My issue is I don't know where to enter these commands.

I've tried in mysql workbench but it only accept normal sql code.

Comment: It's a command-line interface. If you're on Windows use PowerShell or Prompt. On OSX/Linux you can use Terminal and call the mysqladmin command that lives in the $PATH somewhere.

Comment: This is not sql code, you'll have to type into linux terminal

Comment: So how would that work, I work on Windows and I'm trying stuff in command prompt but I'm encountering the same errors.

Comment: @seetler, Maybe you should post the errors?

Comment: It's not errors, its more like I don't know where to input it, I get stuff like this "'mysqladmin' is not a recognized as an internal or external command". I just entered this into command prompt

Comment: @seetler, That means you either have to add the path where the executable is to the command prompt run path (whatever that's called) or use like `cd c:\wheremymysqlisinstalled\bin\` to move to the directory where the executable resides.

Answer (score 1):

If your MySQL bin is not in your path variable then you first need to navigate to the folder where these commands reside.

For MySQL 5.5 the path was: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin

In a command-prompt, you can use the "cd" command to change you directory. e.g.:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin"
```

Also, if you are on Windows 7 and more comfortable using Windows Explorer. Click the start orb and then click Computer. Open Local Disk (C:) and then look in Program Files\MySQL. Open the folder for the version of MySQL you have. You can then hold down the Shift key and right-click on the bin folder. From the context menu choose "**Open command window here**".

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful, I think it got me closer. I still get the following eeor "mysqladmin is not a recognized as a cmdlet, function, operable program, or script file." I'll troubleshoot a bit more myself.

Comment: @seetler Are you doing this in a PowerShell window? If so you need to prefix it with .\

Comment: Example: .\mysqladmin